# Comparar si una cadena contiene palabra

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente problema

Necesito hacer un if que compare si una palabra esta dentro de una cadena separada por espacios, y que no sea sensible a mayus/minus.

```js
var name = "Lupa 163";
 
 if (name == 'lupa'){
     console.log("Es verdad");
}
else{
  console.log("Es mentira");
}
```

Comment: Define que son para ti `dos strings no exactamente iguales`. Sin eso es imposible ayudarte

Comment: Me refiero a dos palabras, igual me he expresado mal

Comment: Lo que veo que estás haciendo es decidir si una cadena contiene una determinada palabra, independiente de may/min. En cuyo caso, deberías definir un máximo de palabras en la cadena, lo que consideras un separador o lo que consideras una palabra. Sin eso, la pregunta no está clara.

Comment: Si, ese es el caso, decidir si una cadena tiene una palabra. No se como lograr hacerlo

Comment: Conoces el metodo `indexOf`????

Comment: Por favor, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/224930/edit) la pregunta y coloca los requisitos: sensible a may/min, si está delimitada por espacios o por otros caracteres, que caracteres pueden formar parte de la palabra, ... Cuando lo tengas claro, las [Expresiones Regulares](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Regular_expression) son lo que estás buscando :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías utilizar el `includes()` de javascript para ver si la cadena contiene lo que necesitas y el `toUpperCase()` o `toLowerCase()` para insensibilizar el string.

```js
var name = "Lupa 163";
name = name.toUpperCase();
 
if (name.includes(' LUPA ')){
     console.log("Es verdad");
}
else{
  console.log("Es mentira");
}

name = " Lupa 163";
name = name.toUpperCase();
if (name.includes(' LUPA ')){
     console.log("Es verdad");
}
else{
  console.log("Es mentira");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que estas buescando creo que es la funcion `.search()` seria algo asi:

```js
var text = "EnCuEnTrA La PaLaBrA";

//normalizando
text = text.toLowerCase();
text = text.trim();

$("#output").append("Primera busqueda : ");
if (text.search("     palabra    ".trim()) != -1)
    $("#output").append("verdad");
else
    $("#output").append("mentira");
    
$("#output").append("<br/> Segunda busqueda : ");
    
if (text.search("nada") != -1)
    $("#output").append("verdad");
else
    $("#output").append("mentira");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output">
</div>
```

esta funcion te devuelve la posición de la palabra que buscas y si no esta presente retorna -1.

para el case sensitive prodrias usar `txt.toUpperCase()` o `txt.toLowerCase()` para normalizar los fragmentos y para mas seguridad podrias utilizar la funcion `txt.trim()` para evitar tener espacios extra

Espero que te sea de ayuda